# Can somebody please test this font, and let me know the right CSS code?

Tags: css, font-family

http://www.1001freefonts.com/kimberley.font

I am trying to implement this font on a web page. I have tried using this code, but the font doesn't change at all.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Kimberley';
src: url(kimbalt_.tff);
```

}

I am sorry, but I know this is too noobish.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the license agreement allows embedding? See the [licensing info on myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/kimberley/licensing.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a web font version of the font. If you have purchased a license for the font you can make a web version on an online fontface convertor such as [fontsquirrel.com](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

Then you need to upload your fonts (there will be more font formats included) and in the src attribute you need to provide the link to the font. An example for @fontface

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```